# Adding a row-dependent value to each row

Tags: numpy, constants, addition

I have a 2D array containing the following numbers:

```
A = [[1, 5, 9, 42],
     [20, 2, 71, 0],
     [2, 44, 4, 9]]
```

I want to add a different constant value to each row without using loops. This value is a n*c with n being the current row and c being the constant. For example, c=100 so that:

```
B = [[1, 5, 9, 42],
     [120, 102, 171, 100],
     [202, 244, 204, 209]]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that as follows:

```
>>> A = [[1, 5, 9, 42],
...      [20, 2, 71, 0],
...      [2, 44, 4, 9]]
...      

>>> a = np.array(A)
>>> c = 100

>>> addto = np.arange(len(a))[:, None] * c

>>> a + addto
array([[  1,   5,   9,  42],
       [120, 102, 171, 100],
       [202, 244, 204, 209]])
```

---

`np.arange(len(a))` gets you a 1-dimensional array of the indices, `array([0, 1, 2])`, which you can then multiply by `c`.

The hitch is that you then need to conform this to NumPy's [broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules) by expanding it's dimensionality:

```
>>> np.arange(len(a)).shape
(3,)

>>> np.arange(len(a))[:, None].shape
(3, 1)
```

You could also do something like `np.linspace(0, 100*(len(a)-1), num=len(a))[:, None]`, but that is probably overkill here.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: No prob, happy to help